# git log -p without contents of deleted files

Tags: git, git-log, git-repo

I'm assigned to a task to delete unnecessary files from our git repository. This results in deleting many files and editing few others. When I issue `git show` or `git log -p` my screen is flooded with the contents of the deleted files and I can hardly find the meaningful parts which are the modifications I made in the other files.

Illustration:

```
--- a/path/to/a/file
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1,41 +0,0 @@
-Lots of content I don't want to see.
-Lots of content I don't want to see.
-Lots of content I don't want to see.
-Lots of content I don't want to see.
-Lots of content I don't want to see.
-...
```

Is there any way to suppress displaying the contents of deleted files?

Comment: Separate deletion and modification into different revisions.

Comment: @eftshift0 Not a bad idea. But deleting files and deleting the references from other files to them and committing these actions as one seems desirable for me. Registered your idea as a workaround :-)

Comment: You might do it the other way around: delete the references, then delete the files themselves.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be

```sh
git show 3764981273649817263498712 \
  | sed '/^\+\+\+ \/dev\/null/,/^diff/d' \
  | colordiff \
  | less -R
```

**Note**

If the output of `git show` is not interactive (piped to other command) then it will not be colored and a pager (like `less`) will not be invoked. Invoking `colordiff` and then `less -R` solves this problem.

**Con**

The output is not precise, but good enough for humans.